# Github Action Status check missing from the list of checks in Protected branch settings

Tags: github, github-actions

I have the following github action setup that triggers fine on creation of Pull Request. But it does not show up in the status checks list of protected branch (main). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
name: Python application

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Set up Python 3.7
      uses: actions/setup-python@v1
      with:
        python-version: 3.7
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    - name: Lint with flake8
      run: |
        pip install flake8
        # stop the build if there are Python syntax errors or undefined names
        flake8 . --count --select=E9,F63,F7,F82 --show-source --statistics
        # exit-zero treats all errors as warnings. The GitHub editor is 127 chars wide
        flake8 . --count --exit-zero --max-complexity=10 --max-line-length=127 --statistics
    - name: GitHub Action for pylint
      uses: cclauss/GitHub-Action-for-pylint@0.7.0
    - name: Github Action for pytest
      run: python3 testing.py
```

I've also tried the same setting with:

```
on: [ pull_request ]
```

Edit:
Screenshot of the check missing:
[image]

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Finally figured this out. I did not set a name for the job, so it defaulted to the property, `build`, in this case. I was searching by workflow name. Once I added the job name, I was able to search for it correctly. Later I also verified that searching for "build" brings up the check name in the list too.

```
jobs:
  build:
    name: python test
...
```

Comment: my job has name but it is not listed in status check

Comment: You can also omit `build:` and `name:` and just indent the name of the job after `jobs:` on next line. Then if you type that name in the search bar, it will show up. This would be for a non-build case of course.

Comment: How does github handle names that aren't unique?  You would think people end up with lots of actions that run the default "build" job name

Answer (score 2):

I just had a similar experience but it was because my Github Workflow had not been triggered in the past week. Once I got the Workflow to trigger it showed up in the search area.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution may be to go to `https://github.com/<org_name>/<repo_name>/actions` and check to see if there's a button that says

> Enable Actions on this repository

Then try closing/opening your existing PR to trigger the action.