# Automate filter files on pull request

Tags: github, github-app

I have created a github repo and deployed a simple HTML, CSS and JS website on it.

I want to create a github bot to automatically filter the pull request on the following basis:

```
If only the JS file is changed then the pull request is valid else it is invalid
```

Is it really possible to do that?
Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could use a GitHub Action for that.

For instance, [`banyan/auto-label`](https://github.com/banyan/auto-label) applies label based on file type.

In your case, fork that repository, and make your own GitHub Action in order to reject the PR if you detect a file whose extension is not the one set in your action.

A rejection ("[mergeability of PR](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests)") can involve [status check policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58655352/6309).

Comment: ok thanks for the help. I will surely try it and get back to you